# Wait till all CCActions on different CCSprites are complete

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccaction

I am developing a simple cocos2d game in which I want to animate two `CCSprite`s simultaneously, and for this purpose I simply set `CCAction`s on respective `CCSprite's as follows.

```
[first runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:secondPosition]];
[second runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:firstPosition]];
```

Now I want to wait till the animations are complete, so I can perform the next step. How should I **wait** for these animations to finish?

There are actually two method calls, the first one animates the objects via the code above and second call does the other animation.

I need to delay the second method call until the animations in first are complete. (I would not like to use `CCCallBlock` blocks as I want to call the second method from the same caller as the first one.

**EDIT**

I tried this ..

```
__block BOOL moving = YES;
[second runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:firstPosition], [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode *node){
            CCLOG(@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nMovement Finished\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
            moving = NO;
        }],nil]];
while(moving);
```

But the `CCCallBlock` never gets called thus forever stuck in `while` loop =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I wouldn't dig it out of cocos's docs, I would implement my own observer object, to observe if a group of animations have been finished. It will require few quick steps:

1. Create your own class like `PendingOperationsCounter`
2. Instantiate object of `PendingOperationsCounter`
3. Register finish action for this particular `PendingOperationsCounter`
4. Register every starting animation to your `PendingOperationsCounter`, when registering increase pending operations counter
5. When animation finishes it decreases operations counter
6. If counter is zero again, it fires its own finish action you've registered

Done!

Comment: Sorry for being naive but a piece of code could really help here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a simple CCMoveTo in first, use a CCSequence with 1) the MoveTo, and 2) a CallBlock to start second. In the call block to start second, use again a CCSequence for 1) the moveTo, and 2) call a selector to do whatever you want to do. It will work in THIS use case. For a more generic approach, follow the above answer as a guideline.